# Booting livecd from external USB not working (no power?)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, livecd

I have a usb hard drive with ubuntu 12.10 partition on it, but I can't seem to actually boot into the livecd.

I can get to the grub menu, and I select "Try without installing", but then the screen just goes blank. I've tried leaving it for a while, but it was still blank, and switching to another tty didn't work either. It appears that my external hard drive powers off. It's a 2.5" drive, so there's no external power or anything like that.

I can mount and access the files fine when I'm in windows and linux. It's formatted as FAT32 (w95), with another NTFS partition on it. Am I just missing something when making it bootable, or is there a bios setting to keep power to the hdd?

Comment: You might want to try asking this on the Ask Ubuntu StackExchange, as it seems to be related to Ubuntu (possibly drivers?)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a spare 4GB USB stick? Install Ubuntu on it using Unetbootin. I've done that many times. I don't know why the same procedure wouldn't work via an external HD with different partitions, but I think this is the easiest thing to try. Then you could remove the partitions on the HD and try again. FAT32 should work for the stick.

Comment: I kind of want it on the hdd, actually ;) Other than that I guess I could just try reinstalling it again, but I don't understand what's wrong. Getting to GRUB means that it's bootable.